# Is this possible to get total number of rows count with offset limit

Tags: mysql, merge, count, offset

Hey Guyz Is this possible to get total number of rows count with offset limit

Scenario

```
SELECT * FROM users limit 0,5;
```

This Query contain 300 records but the issue is if i call this query with offset the result will be show only 5 record and i don't want to write a Query in twice time. one for paging limit and other for total no of record count...

> I don't want this

```
SELECT * FROM users limit 0,5; // paging 
SELECT count(*) FROM users; // count
```

i have to merge this Queries or helps are definitely appreciated

Comment: 1) Why not run them separately? 2) Do you have an extra `limit` clause in the `count` query?

Comment: This is the short example of query and i have a huge query that why i don't want to write a query in twice time @MostyMostacho

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS like this

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM users limit 0,5;
```

It gets the row count *before* applying any LIMIT clause. It does need another query to fetch the results but that query can simply be

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

and hence you don't have to repeat your complicated query.