# How to execute query in and get count of total elements without running twice with Rails 4 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I´m running a cost-time query in MySQL and Rails. This query is created dynamically and it also manages pagination with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. This is a summarized example:

```
SELECT fields
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY order DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

I would also like to get the total count of elements, but I would like to avoid run the query twice for performance purposes. I don´t think is possible, but maybe you surprise me :)

Currently, I have something like:

```
objects = Object.find_by_sql(query)    
totalCount = objects.count
```

But, of course, this is always returning the limit count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using pagination and offsetting, you're not going to get a complete result. You can either run the two separate queries, or you can pull the complete dataset and then filter for pagination. The first option is likely to be faster, especially as your dataset grows.

To improve performance you'd getter better results looking at a caching strategy at various points. Without knowing when the data changes I can't offer any specific advice.

**Edit 1: Expanding for Clarification**

It might help to explain why this is the case. When you put into place the limit and offset manually, Rails knows nothing about the data not returned by the query. So without having that data available, it's definitionally impossible to make Rails aware of the total count.

That said, a simple `COUNT` aggregation should always be very fast to execute. If you're seeing speed issues with the execution of that query you'll want to make sure you have the right indexes in place, and that Rails is rendering the conditions in an optimal format.

Comment: I think the solution is to run the query twice. One with fields and limits (pagination) and the other one only with count and without limits.

Comment: That definitely seems like the fastest option right? But check on the conditions being generated. While it's far less likely with Rails due to the nature of how it handles things, I've seen major performance issues in SAS and Oracle eliminated when the conditions involve functions.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL? Why not to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with FOUND_ROWS() ?

With two queries: (the second query will not hit the database)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM users LIMIT 0,5;
SELECT COUNT(FOUND_ROWS()) AS rows_count FROM users;
```

But one advise: you must test it. This might be slower or faster than two queries, it depends on some factors, like caching, engine, indexes, etc...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

[Is this possible to get total number of rows count with offset limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084413/is-this-possible-to-get-total-number-of-rows-count-with-offset-limit)

Answer (score 0):

To Count the records just add one query as a column to your dynamically created query.

Check this:

```
SELECT fields,(SELECT count(*) FROM tables WHERE conditions) as obj_count
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY order DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

Using MySQL session variables(starting with symbol `@`) we can write more efficient query.

```
SELECT fields,@count as obj_count 
FROM tables,(SELECT @count:=count(*) FROM tables WHERE conditions) as sub
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY order DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

Comment: I'm curious if a sub-select is the right way to go here, wouldn't that run the count query for each record returned?

Comment: I imagine another option is to join the data set object to a query you generate yourself with the count data. But I'm also then curious how Rails renders an object if it gets unanticipated columns back. Looking at `find_by_sql` it only appears to include columns relevant to the model being returned.

Comment: If you read the issue, you can see we are trying to get a solution in order to get the best performance.

Comment: @Rober: check the updated query which is more efficient then previous one as it counts the objects in one shot not for all rows.

Comment: @Code-Monk Still not clear on how the records are being instantiated...?

Comment: query which i have written in `from` clause will store record count in `@count` variable.

Comment: @Code-Monk Is that how they get instantiated by Rails? Is the count variable going to show up as an instance variable on each of the records?

Comment: Yeah...count will  show up as an column for each of the records. What you have to do is to pick one the value for your purpose. did you get my point?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not being clear? :) When I say record, I'm referring to an instance of an ActiveRecord object in Rails. So while I understand that the SQL query set will return the count column as you've described, it's not clear how this will be accessible within the context of the `find_by_sql` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95380/discussion-between-code-monk-and-richard-seviora).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but try using objects.length. Length will count what you already have in the array.